# How to get data from the second intent call to one Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm building a small quiz app with 3 activities A, B, C.
A startActivity() to B.
B has a fragment B_frag to show the quiz detail, after finish the quiz B_frag will startActivity() to C which is the result activity. 
C has an option to redo the quiz which will startActivity() to B again, this time with a string through intent.putExtra().
The problem is nothing comes out of the intent.getStringExtras() on activity B after being called from C.
Can someone pls tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: show some code how you are putting data to intent and getting from it

Comment: please put your code to of sending and receiving data from C to B

Answer (score 0):

From the `Activity` C try to use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) when you call `startActivity()` to start `Activity` B. Then in `Activity` B override [onNewIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to get the new intent from `Activity` C.

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code.
For sending data from Activity A to Activity B, try this:

```
intent.putExtra("someKey", yourView.getText().toString());
```

In Activity B:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle!=null){
        yourString= bundle.getString("someKey", "no name");
    }
yourView.setText(yourString);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting flag new task when calling startactivity from c to b.

Comment: Setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is completely useless when you call `startActivity()` from one of your own activities, as the `Activity` will always be launched into the current task (unless you have explicitly set `taskAffinity` in the manifest. Also, this flag has no effect whatsoever on extras in the `Intent`.